# How to solve the Gem::LoadError in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

I am new to Ruby, previously I installed an older Ruby and gem versions and I create one sample project.

Now I...

- uninstall the Ruby and all using uninstall program via control panel.
- install new versions of ruby and all.
- run the server - it throws a lot of errors.

I solved some problems but I am not able to solve the Gem::LoadError and rake db:migrate errors.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `gem sqlite3` into your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle` in console.

It should look something like this

## Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: gem 'sqlite3' throw error like                                            ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command sqlite3

Comment: and i use $ gem install sqlite3 it's throw different error 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sqlite3' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A (https
://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Where is your `Gemfile` located? It should be in the root of your project.Have a look on this working code, [sample app in rails](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/Gemfile)

Comment: From strating i am using Aptana3 IDE in Eclipse and i use the first command your post like gem 'rails', '3.2.3' it's always throw ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command rails,

Comment: and i execute these all commands in my application terminal using Aptana3 IDE

Comment: I am using Aptana IDE, When i create a new rail application, that i automatically create all files like these are my files              $ ls
Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.rdoc  Rakefile  app  bin  config  config.ru  db  lib  log  public  test  tmp  vendor                   All files are under my application name only.